# Get result of a function jquery

Tags: jquery, function, syntax, return, scrolltop

I create a function for getting the currrent scrollTop of the window :

```
function scroll(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
    return pos;
}
```

I would like to get the current result outside my function for use it on others functions of my script, for example :

```
function navOpen() {
    $('header').css('top','-' pos);
}
```

It doesn't work like that. I can't recover my scrollTop value.
Idea ?

Comment: Define the variable as global, i.e. outside the function.

Comment: or just don't use var. That will hoist the variable to the global name space. Unconventional, but it works.

Comment: Your function scroll does not make a lot of sens. Each time you call this function you are adding an event listener to the dom. I guess is not what your are expecting.

Comment: @nicael as global ? how do you write this ?

Comment: *i.e. outside the function*

Comment: @mathk if I just use a variable  `var pos = $(window).scrollTop();` I can't get the current value but just the value when the page load. That's why I looking for write an outside function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: About pos variable  define it outside functions cause if you define it in function it will return undefined

2nd: About window scroll event which will update pos .. it will not update pos variable till you run function scroll()  then it will updated with new $(window).scrollTop()

3rd: About navOpen() it will not update itself it should update inside another event .. to get the updated pos value

4th: in your code you forgot + sign before pos

```
$('header').css('top','-' pos);
```

it should be

```
$('header').css('top','-'+ pos);
```

so your code should be something like this

```
var pos= 0;
function scroll(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
       pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
    return pos;
}
function navOpen() {
    alert(pos);
    //$('header').css('top','-'+pos);
}

scroll(); // run scroll function here to update pos
//navOpen(); // you can run it here but for sure it will return 0;
$('button').on('click',function(){
    navOpen();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nuj1muwk/3/)

Comment: Oh thanks, I understand my mistake. But 'console.log(pos);' return always 0 even if I update the scroll position with the function.

Comment: @BrownBe  in my demo scroll the window and click on button  its not always 0  .. it will return 0  on load  and if window scrollTop = 0

Comment: you should remove the `return pos`, its causing confusion and is unnecessary, but so is the `scroll` function. just use the global (if thats how you roll) and add the handler. the extra function call is unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef right ! my function was at the wrong place. Thanks it work !

Comment: @BrownBe first I'm glad it helped .. but honestly its not a good way to achieve that.. Maybe I don't have a good idea about what you trying to do   but I think there are better things more than this way .. anyway You're welcome .. and very good luck to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to correct the header top attribute upon every scroll, you would do it like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (){
  $('header').css('top','-' + $(window).scrollTop());
}
```

In your code the problem is also the fact that in Javascript variables are scoped to functions, so your `pos` where you assign the scrollTop value is only visible within the scroll-event-handling anonymous function, and not within the `scroll()` function.

```
function scroll(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    //The above variable is only visible within the function it was declared in
  });
  return pos; //this is an undeclared variable, trying to return it will throw an error
}
```

If you want to both have the easily available global variable and properly working assignment/handling, you could do:

```
var globalPos = 0; //declaring the global var

function updateGlobalPos(){ 
    globalPos = $(window).scrollTop(); //assigning the value upon scroll
}

function updateCss(){
    $('header').css('top','-' + globalPos); //correcting the css upon scroll
}

//attaching handlers to scroll event
$(window).on('scroll', updateGlobalPos);     
$(window).on('scroll', updateCss);
```

And now you have your value available and always up to date in the `globalPos` variable, plus you have your css corrected every scroll.

Friendly advise: you should throttle scroll handlers, cause scroll event happens waaaay too often and it might take quite a lot of cpu power.

Comment: This certainly solves the problem, but I think the OP is asking for a general-case solution.

Comment: pos is not global, its undefined and will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare  your variable outside your function.

```
var pos = 0;
function scroll(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
    return pos;
}
function navOpen() {
    $('header').css('top','-' pos);
}
```

That is how you pass the value.

Comment: you should remove the `return pos`, in the example its unnecessary I doubt the OP ever wants it as the return value. Globals are mega troublesome, but they are the easiest solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scroll(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
    return pos;
}
```

There is a fair amount awry here. For a start, invoking `scroll` should throw you an error as `pos` won't be defined. You might be tempted to stick `pos` at the top of the scroll function and return it later but it wont work, for many reasons.

Why are you worried about calling `scrollTop` wherever you need it?

```
function navOpen() {
    $('header').css('top', -$( window ).scrollTop() );
}
```

I wouldnt recommend wrapping `window` in $ all the time though.